# Feature Layer Selection MVVM Silverlight

Tags: arcgis-silverlight-api, silverlight, model-view-viewmodel

In my current project I have multiple feature layers which comes on Map when User Click on it. I'm able to represent them by MVVM on Map.
Now when User click /select by square area on layer, available geometry on it should be highlighted. I have to show the details of it on info Window. This data I need it in my viewModel for Highlight Grid Selected Rows Visibility too.

I am able to select the geometries by 
https://developers.arcgis.com/silverlight/sample-code/start.htm#FeatureLayerSelection

But I m not getting the selected Data in my ViewModel & I m unable to show the infowindow by MVVM and Highlight selected Roads.